# Can I change the jump force of my character's physics in BGE while in runtime mode?

Tags: python, game-engine, physics

I want to be able to change the jump force for my character while the game is running. Is this possible using python and without using the "bpy" namepsace? yes I have my character set to "Character" in the "Physics" tab and it is also in "Blender Game" mode.

Comment: unfortunately jump force is not accessible through the bge module. https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bge.types.KX_CharacterWrapper.html